# Explanation of Mapbox Android v10 RenderedQueryOptions

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I am learning Mapbox SDK for Android and having difficulty understanding the syntax for `RenderedQueryOptions` in `queryRenderedFeatures` v10.  I am able to retrieve a JSON result from a `ScreenBox`, but the use of layerIds and filters is a mystery to me.

Can someone recommend a guide or example for Mapbox Android v10 `RenderedQueryOptions`?  For example, how are layerIds and filters used to retrieve specific results?  I am looking for a general explanation, but clear examples are also useful.

I checked several sources and not yet found a good explanation:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/ (no instruction for RenderedQueryOptions)
- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/legacy/maps/guides/query/ (useful for v9, but not v10)
- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/view-annotation-showcase/ (no explanation of filters)
- https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/tilequery/ (looks similar to v9, not v10)
- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-maps-android (did not find a clear example)

Answer (score 0):

I found the `RenderedQueryOptions()` in Android is much easier to understand from the JavaScript documentation.

From the [Android documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/api/10.4.3/mapbox-maps-android/com.mapbox.maps/-rendered-query-options/):

```
RenderedQueryOptions(layerIds: List<String>, filter: Value)
```

- `layerIds` is analogous to [Layer in JS](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/), as in [Data sources from Mapbox-Streets-v8](https://docs.mapbox.com/data/tilesets/reference/mapbox-streets-v8/#data-sources-and-updates).
- `filter` seems analogous to [Expression Types in JS](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#types), although I have only seen `literal(true)` used in practice (on GitHub).